# Django, matching query does not exist with existing db row

Tags: django, database, django-models

I got strange issue with Django ORM.
Here's `Action` objects with id 1 and 6, but a can't get first by id.
Both of them exist in database.

```
In [17]: Action.objects.get(code='check_email').pk
Out[17]: 6L

In [18]: Action.objects.get(code='periodic_order_check').pk
Out[18]: 1L

In [19]: Action.objects.get(pk='6')
Out[19]: <Action: Check Email>

In [20]: Action.objects.get(pk='1')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DoesNotExist                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-728196789a45> in <module>()
----> 1 Action.objects.get(pk='1')

/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/vagrant/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.pyc in manager_method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    120         def create_method(name, method):
    121             def manager_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 122                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
    123             manager_method.__name__ = method.__name__
    124             manager_method.__doc__ = method.__doc__

/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/vagrant/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cacheops/query.pyc in get(self, *args, **kwargs)
    351             qs = self
    352 
--> 353         return qs._no_monkey.get(qs, *args, **kwargs)
    354 
    355     def exists(self):

/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/vagrant/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.pyc in get(self, *args, **kwargs)
    385             raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
    386                 "%s matching query does not exist." %
--> 387                 self.model._meta.object_name
    388             )
    389         raise self.model.MultipleObjectsReturned(

DoesNotExist: Action matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: You can try disabling cacheops or clearing its cache with `manage.py invalidate all`.

Comment: @Suor thank you, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you use

```
Action.objects.all().values()
```

to check all the values and see if your get query is correct. Since the field you are using is pk (provided it's the primary key and you have not redefined it), passing string '1' should not work anyways. Check the models and field types as well as values for all fields.